# Get firebase storage reference from full url on Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-storage

How do I create a firebase storage reference from download url (full string path of the file) on flutter. There is **refFromURL** api on android and web to get a reference, however, this is not available on flutter.

I tried following with no success.

```
   StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(url);
   Uint8List data = await ref.getData(0x3FFFFFFF);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this PR](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1208) there should be a [`getReferenceFromUrl` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/FirebaseStorage/getReferenceFromUrl.html). Did you try that?